# Reference external data source from AI/Kusto query?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

***tl;dr:*** *I want to reference an external data source from a Kusto query in Application Insights.*

My application is writing logs to Application Insights, and we're querying it using Kusto in the Azure portal. To give an example of what I'm trying to do:

We're currently looking at these logs to find an action that triggers when a visitor viewed a blog post on our site. This is working well on a per blog-post level, but now we want to group this data by the category these blog posts are in, or by the tags they have, but that's not information I have within the logs.

The information we log contains unique info about that blog post (unique url, our internal id, etc) that I could use to look up this information in another data source (e.g. our SQL DB where this relation is stored), but I have no idea if/how this is possible. So that's the question, is this possible? Can I query a SQL DB, or get data in JSON via a URL or something?

Alternative solutions would be to move the reporting elsewhere (e.g. PowerBI) and just use AI as a data source, or to actually log all the category/tag info, but I really don't want to go down that route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kusto supports accessing external data (blobs, Azure SQL, Cosmos DB), however
Application Insights / Azure Monitor and other multi-tenant services are blocking this functionality due to security and resource governance concerns.

You could try setting-up your own Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) cluster, where this functionality will be available, and then access your Application Insights data using cross-cluster query, or by exporting the data from Application Insights and hooking up EventGrid ingestion into your Kusto cluster.

Relevant links:

Kusto supporting external data:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/externaltables

Querying data inside Application Insights:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/query-monitor-data

Continuous export data from Application Insights:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry

Data ingestion into Kusto from EventGrid:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-grid

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know for the future. For now, we just moved reporting to PowerBI, where we're combining the two data sources into one model; works well so far.